# Trouble adding Logout Button to Tab Fragment Class?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I recently made a simple app that allows users to register information, login, and logout. I want to increase the complexity of this app by adding a tabbed activity that the user sees when they login, and having the third tab contain a TextView that will log them out.

Here is what I did previously to log out in my Main Activity before adding tabs:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Button bLogout;
    private Session session;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        session = new Session(this);
        if(!session.loggedin()){
            logout();
        }
        bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
        bLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                logout();
            }
        });
    }

    private void logout(){
        session.setLoggedin(false);
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Now, I want to transfer this same concept to my Tab3 Fragment Class, but I keep getting errors. Here is the Tab3 class without errors:

```
public class Tab3User extends Fragment{
    private TextView tvLogout;
    private Session session;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3User, container, false);

        tvLogout = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvLogout);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

The errors happen when I try to create a new session using this as Context, as well as in the 'startActivity' method in my logout function when I try to use 'Tab3User.this'. The onClickListener seems to be working, but I am very new to android dev so I'm sure I'm just making a mistake. Here is my attempt to add in everything:

```
public class Tab3User extends Fragment{
    private TextView tvLogout;
    private Session session;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3User, container, false);

        tvLogout = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvLogout);
        return rootView;

        //error here under the "this"
        session = new Session(this);

        if(!session.loggedin()){
            logout();
        }
        tvLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                logout();
            }
        });
    }

    private void logout(){
        session.setLoggedin(false);
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(Tab3User.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }

}
```

Thanks for any and all help. I've been looking online but many answers to questions like this are very ambiguous so I decided to post.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a fragment you need to use getContext() / getActivity().

```
session = new Session(getContext());
```

Comment: You have to keep in mind that Fragments exist to simplify managing of complex views, but they are not activities on their own.